# Ionic 3 PWA not updating smoothly on iOS

Tags: ios, caching, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

We built a PWA with Ionic 3, which is a multiple page application. We host this on a linux server with nginx and use Laravel as a backend

**The situation** 
We have seen that a update to a PWA is not always instantly, our client requested that if we released a update this would happen instantly and automatically.

**What we tried**

1. File based caching: 
   Our first thought was to use the concept of (old fashioned?) cache busting, so when building the app we use a random hash string in the filename. This ended up causing a major issue: Some PWA’s seem to hold on to the old `index.html`. In our access log we can see that old files get requested. The result being people will see a white screen after the splash screen. The only way for them to fix it is to reinstall the PWA completely.
2. Url based caching:
   We devised a new plan: instead of using random hash string in the filename we moved in to the folder name. The request path would look like this: `./build/98312uj91eh9u2e/vendor.js`. With NGINX we remove the hash and serve the same file, so it will return the the file from this path: `./build/vendor.js`. This caused another issue where files would be mismatched. So some user would have parts of the old version and parts of the news versions which caused a lot of random issues.
3. Hosting multiple versions hoping they would update:
   This pretty much did nothing other than creating lot of confusion. because some PWA’s would never update some people would be stuck on a old version and not see the new features.

**Our current idea**
Instead of using a static html file we are thinking of using javascript to make an API call to the backend of the PWA. Which will return a string with the current version of the PWA. This version will be the random string contain within the file names. This way, regardless of index.html updates, the content well be dynamic and not cause issue before description issues.

**So what is the question?**
Is it a good idea to make use of the concept where we would use JavaScript for making an API call or would this cause other issues we have not thought about yet.

Comment: Out of curiosity are you guys using Ionic Deploy to push live updates to the clients?

Comment: We don't use ionic deploy anymore because we've stopped using it as an app.

Comment: So just confirming here, you guys push the code to the server and the site should be updated. I'm assuming they use safari or chrome? You're question seems like you want to add a javascript hook to your PWA.